# Php running all code above it

Tags: php, html

I am building a website and I am new to php. When you try to add a baterang to cart it just adds a baterang but when you add a tripleX it adds a triplex and baterang. Please Help.

Here is my main page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
</script>   

</head>

<body>
<main class="container">
<?php
$Items = $_GET["newItems"];
$cart = explode("+",$Items)
?>
<div>
<div class="nav">   ‍   
<img id="logo" width="40" src="/images/logo-main.png"/> Spinners3d.com 
| <a id="home" href="http://spinners3d.com" style="text-
decoration:none; color:white;" >Home</a> | <a id="help" 
href="http://spinners3d.com/help.html" style="text-decoration:none; 
color:white;" >Support</a> | <a id="cart" 
href="http://spinners3d.com/cart.php" style="text-decoration:none; 
color:white;" >Cart</a>
<br>
</div>
<div class="spinners">
Spinners
<br>
    ‍    
<br>
<img width="60" src="/images/hillary.jpg"/>
<br>
Baterang
<br>
<a href="http://spinners3d.com/cart.php?newItem=<?php array_push($cart, 
'Baterang'); echo $tran = implode('+', $cart);?>" style="text-
decoration:none; color:#4fa7ff;" >Add To Cart</a>
<br>
    ‍   
<br>   
<img width="60" src="/images/hillary.jpg">
<br>
TripleX
<br>
<a href="http://spinners3d.com/cart.php?newItem=<?php array_push($cart, 
'TripleX'); echo $tran = implode('+', $cart);?>" style="text-
decoration:none; color:#4fa7ff;" >Add To Cart</a>
<br>
    ‍   
<br>   
<img width="60" src="/images/hillary.jpg"/>
<br>
The Dragon
<br>
<a href="http://spinners3d.com/cart.php?newItem=<?php array_push($cart, 
'TheDragon'); echo $tran = implode('+', $cart);?>" style="text-
decoration:none; color:#4fa7ff;" >Add To Cart</a>
<pre>
<?php print_r($cart); ?>
</pre>
</div>

</main>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is the cart page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
   <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
   <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
   <script>

   </script>
   </head>

   <body>
   <?php $newItems = $_GET[newItem];?>
   <?php $cart = explode("+",$newItems);?>
   <div class="nav">
   <img id="logo" width="40" src="/images/logo-main.png"/> 
   Spinners3d.com | 
   <a id="home" href="http://spinners3d.com?newItems=<?php echo $tran = 
   implode('+', $cart); ?>" style="text-decoration:none; color:white;" 
   >Home</a> | <a id="help" href="http://spinners3d.com/help.html" 
   style="text-decoration:none; color:white;" >Support</a> | <a 
   id="cart" 
   href="http://spinners3d.com/cart.php" style="text-decoration:none; 
   color:white;" >Cart</a>
   </div>

   <?php foreach($cart as $item);
   echo '<div id=spinners>'.$item.'<div/>';
   ?> 
   </body>

   </html>
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: Code is much easier to read when indented properly, and you're much more likely to get assistance from others when doing so.  While I don't necessarily support the particular approach given in this blog, it aptly demonstrates the visual ease of indentation: https://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/formatting-and-indenting-your-html/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makes sense since this:

```
<a href="http://spinners3d.com/cart.php?newItem=<?php array_push($cart, 
'Baterang'); echo $tran = implode('+', $cart);?>" style="text-
decoration:none; color:#4fa7ff;" >Add To Cart</a>
```

Adds the Baterang item to `$cart`. Don't push stuff to your `$cart` array before you actually follow the link. For now it's adding every item to the cart when displaying the page.

Your link should probably only be something like `?newItem=Baterang`

And this in your cart page:

```
<?php
$newItem = $_GET['newItem'];
array_push($cart, $newItem);
?>
```

I think you're mixing client-side and server-side logic. The push is not done when you click the `<a>` tag like it would be the case in JS, it all happens on the server side when `cart.php` is loaded.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$_GET["newItem"]` ?

Comment: Yep, I was just copy/pasting the current code but didn't really check for typos

Comment: I tried this but on my cart page it doesn't show anything but the newitem is in the tag.